# python error when I use different systems!

Tags: python, version, deprecated

When I use my system, there is no error in my python codes. When I use another system I get this error:(both systems have same version of python)

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/numerix/__init__.py:18: DeprecationWarning: 
**********************************************************
matplotlib.numerix and all its subpackages are deprecated.
They will be removed soon.  Please use numpy instead.
**********************************************************

  warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/networkx/generators/hybrid.py:16: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check_2.py", line 79, in <module>
    G.add_edge(u,v,times=[t])
TypeError: add_edge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'times'
```

Comment: are the matplotlib versions also the same?

Comment: @masti: the error is raised from `networkx` package, so it needs to be checked first.

Comment: @SilentGhost:yes I think the same! it seems that it knows networkx but what is wrong with this line: add_edge()? maybe it's due to matplotlib.numerix package!

Comment: @masti: it's not `add_edge` per se, it just doesn't understand `times` keyword.

Comment: @masti: because keywords to the `add_edge` method were introduced in the networkx release 1.0. If you're using anything older than that (which you probably are), you bound to get this error.

Comment: thanks a lot! the version is 0.99!

Answer (score 4):

There's a hint.

```
matplotlib.numerix and all its subpackages are deprecated.
They will be removed soon.  Please use numpy instead.
```

The system that gets this error has old packages installed.

While the "version of python" may be the same, the set of installed packages is different.

Comment: how can I use numpy as the hint suggests?

Comment: Instead of using functions from `matplotlib.numerix`, use functions from `numpy`. You'll have to look up the documentation.